# Always keep div at the same place relative to the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I have a small menu that I always want to be in the bottom right corner.
Now normally this would be no issue with

```
#element {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

but I am using the [zoomooz](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/) plug in to zoom into several elements on the page.
When this happens, the menu elemnt stays where it originally was.
The plugin uses transform to perform the zoom:

```
transform: translate(-1358.83px, 577.585px) rotate(0rad) skewX(0rad) scale(3.33879, 3.33879); transform-origin: 1280px 667px 0px;
```

What can I do to keep the menu element in the bottom right corner even when the plugin zooms?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the other elements in the page within a container div, which zoomoz works on, then keeping the menu on the top level? (edit: check the "Zooming inside a container" section on the zoomoz page)

Comment: Can you provide a working example?